# How can I hide a table when tbody is empty?

Tags: reactjs

I have 5 different tables and sometimes some of them can be empty (because I change the rendered content with button click) and I want to return a message (the p tag below) when the tbody is empty and hide the whole table (thead and tbody).
I'm using React JS.
My code is pretty simple :

```
<table className={toggleState === 5 ? "active pokemon_moves_table" : "hidden"}>
  <tbody className='pokemon_moves_table_body'>
        {pokemon?.moves?.map((pm) => 
            pm?.version_group_details?.map((pmv) =>
            pmv?.version_group?.name === version && pmv?.move_learn_method?.name === 'level-up' && pmv?.level_learned_at === 0 &&
                <tr className='pokemon_moves_table_body_row'>
                ---------------multiple td's-----------------
                </tr>
  </tbody>
<table>

<p className='pokemon_moves_void'><span>{pokemon?.name?.replace(/-/g, ' ')}</span> ‌‌ doesn't learn any moves this way in Pokémon ‌‌ <span>{game}</span></p>
```

I tried to use ternary operator with .length / .filter() and other methods but it didn't change anything and I have tried with css and :empty btu it also didn't worked.

**UPDATE**

Here's my new code with Mihalyi solution :

```
const rowsEvolution = everything that was in my tbody;

{rowsEvolution?.length !== 0 ? (
    <table className={toggleState === 5 ? "active pokemon_moves_table" : "hidden"}>
        <thead className='pokemon_moves_table_head'>
        </thead>
        <tbody className='pokemon_moves_table_body'>
            {rowsEvolution}
        </tbody>
    </table>
) : (
    <p className='pokemon_moves_void'><span>{pokemon?.name?.replace(/-/g, ' ')}</span> ‌‌ doesn't learn any moves this way in Pokémon ‌‌ <span>{game}</span></p>
)}
```

It doesn't work and return the same than before

Inside my tbody :

```
<tbody className='pokemon_moves_table_body'>
    {pokemon?.moves?.map((pm) => 
        pm?.version_group_details?.map((pmv) =>
        pmv?.version_group?.name === version && pmv?.move_learn_method?.name === 'level-up' && pmv?.level_learned_at === 0 &&
            <tr className='pokemon_moves_table_body_row'>
                <td className='pokemon_moves_table_body_row_element_machine'>
                    -
                </td>
                <td className='pokemon_moves_table_body_row_element'>
                    {pm?.move?.name.replace(/-/g, ' ')}
                </td>
                {move?.map((m) =>
                    m?.name === pm?.move?.name &&
                        <td className='pokemon_moves_table_body_row_element' id={m?.type?.name} style={{"background":"transparent"}}>
                            <img alt={m?.type?.name} />
                        </td>
                )}
                {move?.map((m) =>
                    m?.name === pm?.move?.name &&
                        <td className='pokemon_moves_table_body_row_element'>
                            {m?.damage_class?.name}
                        </td>
                )}
                {move?.map((m) =>
                    m?.name === pm?.move?.name &&
                        <td className='pokemon_moves_table_body_row_element'>
                            {m?.power !== null ? (
                                m?.power
                            ) : (
                                '-'
                            )}
                        </td>
                )}
                {move?.map((m) =>
                    m?.name === pm?.move?.name &&
                        <td className='pokemon_moves_table_body_row_element'>
                            {m?.pp}
                        </td>
                )}
                {move?.map((m) =>
                    m?.name === pm?.move?.name &&
                        <td className='pokemon_moves_table_body_row_element'>
                            {m?.accuracy !== null ? (
                                m?.accuracy
                            ) : (
                                '-'
                            )}
                        </td>
                )}
                {move?.map((m) =>
                    m?.name === pm?.move?.name &&
                        <td className='pokemon_moves_table_body_row_element'>
                            {m?.priority}
                        </td>
                )}
                {move?.map((m) =>
                    m?.name === pm?.move?.name &&
                        <td className='pokemon_moves_table_body_row_element'>
                            {m?.meta?.ailment !== null ? (
                                m?.meta?.ailment?.name?.replace('none', '-')
                            ) : (
                                '-'
                            )}
                        </td>
                )}
            </tr>
        ))}
</tbody>
```

Comment: Can you share how you get `rowsEvolution` and what the data structure looks like?

Comment: @AviCohenNehemia You want to knwo what there is inside my tbody ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to store the children of the tbody in a variable, which you can use to check if has elements or not.

```js
const rows = pokemon?.moves?.map(...);

if (rows.length) {
    return (
        <table>
            <tbody>{rows}</tbody>
        </table>
    );
} else {
    return <p>Empty table!</p>;
}
```

Comment: So I put everything inside the tbody in the const or only the map and the ternary operator and don't touch to the elements inside the tbody ?

Comment: Try to create a single array, not an array of arrays, then you can use a simple length check.  
You can store the React elements in the array, or the original data and map it to React elements later. The length is the same in both ways

Comment: I edited my code with your solution to do but it doesn't work (I'm pretty sure that I did something wrong)

Comment: This works, but i have no idea what your rowsEvolution array looks like.
`
    const elements = [1, 2, 3];

    if (elements.length) {
        return (
            <table>
                <tbody>
                {elements.map(el => <tr>{el}</tr>)}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        );
    } else {
        return <p>No elements</p>
    }
`

Comment: rowsEvolution is the code inside the tbody shown above. What do I put instead of [1, 2, 3] ? Is it possible to do a ternary operator instead of an if else for this situation ?

Comment: - instead of [1,2,3] you put the array of data you want to display (without nested arrays, falsy values, etc.). you can put react elements if you fulfill these requirements.
- Ternary operator basically does the same as if-else.

Comment: But I'm using data coming from an api so I can't put everything in an array